# Error:this template attempted to load content assembly

Tags: vb.net, iphone-developer-program

Ok i recently got visual studio pro just so i could create phone applications in vb.net. Yet when i installed the template i got this error Error:this template attempted to load content assembly. I already have all nuget installed and the error was displaying before i had it so i really need help here. I'm usualy visual studio 2010 ide and trying to load the following temaplte:vb windowsphone application template under silver light. AND SO EVERYONE KNOWS I HAVE TRIED INSTALLING NUGET IT CHANGED NOTHING. Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the link below;
http://www.itorian.com/2012/08/error-this-template-attempted-to-load.html

No the error is not the same. But the error message you provided is only half and cannot know which template/component is giving the error.

Provide the full error to help you better.

Athar

Comment: What I meant was provide the your error message in complete as it is given in the example.

Comment: Ok here Error: this template failed to load content assembly "microsoft.visualstudio.smartdevice.project.systembase version = 10.0.0.0 culture = neutral ,public key token = b03f7f11d50a3a. OK thats the hole message.

Comment: Run VS2010 as Administrator. If you already are, then you will need to remove the older versions of Silverlight and Blend. (ref: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?503140-Windows-7-Phone-and-VB-errors)